# How to define the file storage location in PHP FILE UPLOAD

Tags: php, file-upload

In the following script I tried uploading file to tmp folder in htdocs but the file is not moving to that location. How do I define the storage location?

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
    echo "Upload:    " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type:      " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size:      " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES["file"]["C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp"]` shouldn't exist, try instead:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/path/to/your/upload/directory/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
```

Bare in mind that this code is insecure if you use it *verbatim* (as it is), you need to validate the file mime type (with [the](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) [proper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) [tools](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)) and sanitize the **final** file name at the very least.

Comment: You need to sanitize the actual file, not the mime-time. And the mime-type field is not fully helpful for that because it can be misleading.

Comment: @hakre: I'm confused... I said he needs to validate the mime type (if it's an `image/*` for instance, with the proper tools [like `finfo` / `exif_imagetype`] of course) and sanitize the file name (to not allow  `.htaccess` or `.php` files for instance).

Comment: @hakre: The only scenario where I think file sanitizion is required is with compressed files that are subject to decompression, to avoid Zip bombs, but perhaps I'm not following what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

well the code you posted isn't moving any file. You miss

```
move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key], 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp\new_file.txt' );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Getting error message - Notice: Undefined variable: key in C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: try: move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp\new_file.txt' );